# Pegando valor src de uma imagem pra envio de e-mail em phpmailer

Tags: php, javascript, imagem, table, phpmailer

Na minha página, estou tentando fazer com que seja enviado e-mail com dados de um formulário a ser preenchido. Um dos campos é uma imagem, que pode ser mudada dependendo da opção selecionada:

```
<tr>
<td style="text-align: left">Layout: </td>
<td>
    <select name='layout' style="font-family: Trebuchet MS; font-size: 20px; width: 400px" onchange="document.getElementById('imgCamp').src = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
        <option value="images/campanhas/img0001.jpg">Imagem 1</option>
        <option value="images/campanhas/img0002.jpg">Imagem 2</option>
        <option value="images/campanhas/img0003.jpg">Imagem 3</option>
    </select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><!-- Abaixo é a imagem preview da campanha -->
    <img id="imgCamp" style="width: 560px; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px" src="images/campanhas/img0001.jpg">
</td>
</tr>
```

Mas eu gostaria que no e-mail aparecesse essa imagem selecionada. Segue o código do envio do e-mail abaixo:

```
    if(isset($_POST['btnEnvia'])){ // TODO Falta uma função pra poder enviar o e-mail   
    $unidade        = $_POST['unidade'];
    $solicitante    = $_POST['solicitante'];
    $tipoMaterial   = $_POST['tipoMaterial'];
    $layout         = $_POST['layout'];
    $imgCamp        = 'http://201.7.201.173/MktMaterial/' . 'images/campanhas/img0001.jpg';
    $texto1         = $_POST['texto1'];
    $texto2         = $_POST['texto2'];

    require 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // send via SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'mail.intercityhoteis.com.br'; // SMTP servers
    $mail->Port = 25; // SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'autenticacao@intercityhoteis.com.br'; // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'intercity@123'; // SMTP password
    $mail->From = 'autenticacao@intercityhoteis.com.br';
    $mail->FromName = 'Teste';
    $mail->AddAddress('gustavo.accuser@gmail.com');
    $mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML

    $mail->Subject = 'Solicitação de Material de Marketing - Unidade ' . $unidade;

    // corpo da mensagem
    $mail->Body = '<html>
        <body>
            <div>
                <div style="text-align: center; font-family: Trebuchet MS; font-size: 16px;"><img src="http://201.7.201.173/MktMaterial/images/intercity.png"></img><br><br>Solicitação de material de Marketing:</div>
                <br><br>Unidade: '.$unidade.'
                <br>Solicitante: '.$solicitante.'
                <br>Tipo de Material: '.$tipoMaterial.'
                <br><br>Layout: '.$layout.'
                <br><br><img style="width: 560px; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px" src='.$imgCamp.'>
                <br><br>Texto: '.$texto1.'
                <br><br>Observações: '.$texto2.'
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>';

    // corpo da mensagem em modo texto
    $mail->AltBody = 'Mensagem em texto';

    // verifica se enviou corretamente
    if ( $mail->Send() ) {
        echo "<script>
            alert('Pedido enviado!');
        </script>";
    }
    else {
        echo 'Erro do PHPMailer: ' . $Mailer->ErrorInfo;
    }
}
```

Pensei que a variável $imgCamp poderia receber algo parecido com:

```
$imgCamp = 'http://201.7.201.173/MktMaterial' . ?>$('#imgCamp').val();<?php
```

Sendo que na verdade o que eu quero é que ele receba o valor do src escolhido do imgCamp no meu html. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: O valor de `imgCamp` vai ser sempre igual ao escolhido no campo `select` ?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Como eu posso colocar no código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Então de acordo com seu código html, só pegar o value da select layout, pois o valor dele é o mesmo do src, devido o javascript trocar o src de acordo com o valor de select.

Comment: OK, funcionou!!! Coloquei pra ele receber o valor $_POST['layout']. Obrigado pelas respostas, amigos.